# Destructor ordering in inheritance hierarchy

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, virtual-destructor

If I have the following hierarchy:

- Class F contains member objects of type (Class E and Class D, declared in that order)
- Class F inherits the concrete class Class C
- Class C inherits the abstract/pure virtual class Class B
- Class B inherits the concrete class class A

If the destructor for object of type Class F is called, the following happen in the below order:

1. Class F (the most derived) destructor is called and finishes
2. Class D (member object 2) destructor is called and finishes
3. Class E (member object 1) destructor is called and finishes
4. Class C (base of F) destructor is called and finishes
5. Class A (base of B, which is base of C) destructor is called and finishes
6. Class B (virtual, base of C) destructor is called and finishes

is this correct? So basically towards the end C inherits virtual B and virtual B inherits A, but C gets destroyed, then A, then virtual B?

EDIT: C++ FAQs says:

> "Virtual base classes are special- their destructors are called at the
>   end of the most derived class's constructor"

which is what I am trying to understand?

Comment: The description is a bit confusing: it's not a *class* that is virtual, it's the *inheritance*. So your class C inherits class B virtually, or you can say that B is a *virtual base* of C. Sure, B is abstract and it contains pure virtual functions, but it doesn't matter for order of constructors/destructors.

Comment: @anatolyg so how would you re-word C++FAQs because I am completely confused by what it said?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Destructors execute in reverse order of constructors. That is pretty much all you need to know.

UPDATE: It holds even for virtual bases. You just have to realize that virtual bases are constructed before any other base class.

Comment: Yes but I read that destructors for virtual classes are called at the end, regardless of their position in the hierarchy?

Comment: C++ FAQs, page 272 says "Virtual base classes are special- their destructors are called at the end of the most derived class's constructor". So in my example does this mean immediately after Class F?

Comment: @user997112: You should really add code, rather than a description of what the hierarchy is... are you really using `virtual` inheritance? That is not clear from the description. Please, update the question with real code.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I do not have code, I am trying to understand what the C++ FAQ quote means.

Comment: @user997112: It is unclear what you mean with *abstract/pure virtual class*, I take it you understand what you wrote, just use basic C++ to layout the code...

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it's easiest to express the order of destructor calls as an algorithm.

### Destroy

1. Do whatever the programmer wrote in the destructor's body: `F::~F() { do_this; do_that; }`
2. **Destroy** (call destructors for) members
3. **Destroy** (call destructors for) non-virtual base classes
4. **Destroy** (call destructors for) virtual base classes

This algorithm is performed by the language (or compiler), so the programmer can control only the first step.

Note: each of the further steps is recursive.

The order of destructor calls is the reverse order of constructor calls (it's good to know because the construction order is intuitive). The order of destruction of virtual bases is specified as

> depth-first left-to-right traversal of the graph of base classes

Fortunately, you don't need this because you only have one.

Comment: Ok so in my example I had a virtual base class (Class B) halfway in the inheritance hierarchy between the super class A and class C. Does this mean the destructor for B would get called after both destructors of classes A and C?

Comment: No (just write a test program and follow it in debugger)